# Can't access elements from custom view

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a custom LinearLayout. It contains a TextBox and few other elements.

```
<a.b.c.CustomLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    />
</a.b.c.CustomLinearLayout>
```

I have the following class, from which I'm trying to access the txtTitle element the following way:

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout 
{
    public CustomLinearLayout( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) 
    {
        super( context, attrs );

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.txtTitle );
    }
}
```

But the txtTitle is always null. I also tried to access it like this, but without any luck:

```
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)this.findViewById( R.id.txtTitle );
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)((Activity)context).findViewById( R.id.txtTitle );
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)context.findViewById( R.id.txtTitle );
```

How can I access the TextView from the Context? Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697405/how-to-correctly-extend-linearlayout-to-create-a-custom-view I think you have to inflate your view before you can access the components in it

Comment: @TylerV thanks for the response. That's what I don't understand, isn't it already 'inflated' since I defined the items in the xml or do I still need to inflate it?

Comment: I'm not certain (I've never made a custom LinearLayout before) but looking at the LinearLayout source code here (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java#233) and the ViewGroup code I don't see anything inflating the layout.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15493591/9473786 and try getting the view in `onFinishInflate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access children during the Constructor() because them are not yet loaded and read from the XML. The LinearLayout.Constructor() is the first method called when the XML is parsed and ONLY AFTER it all children are read/parsed, so during the Constructor() them are not accessible/visible/ready_to_use.

Please use:

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
}
```